# Calculate Pi in Swift

Tags: swift, pi

I am working on a mac and want to calculate the digits after the comma as long as the program is running. My problem is, that the number of digits after the comma isn't endless, so how could I make the number as big as I want to?

This is the code I run once the program started:

```
var n = 1.0
var pi = 0.0
while true {
    pi = pi + 4/n
    n = n + 2
    pi = pi - 4/n
    n = n + 2
    print(pi)
}
```

So it still works but just for 14 digits after the comma because of the double.

Comment: You will need your own representation of decimal number.

Comment: @Glorfindel `NSDecimalNumber` isn't going to be significantly different from a `Double` in regards to this question.  It'll be slightly more accurate (base 10 vs base 2), but it won't store any more digits.  The result of using `NSDecimalNumber` for this is `3.141588653589793445064515253761783242225646972656250000000000`, and from using `Double`: `3.141588653589781010566639452008530497550964355468750000000000`.  `NSDecimalNumber` won't make the digits endless.

Comment: Given all the downvotes on answer, change to comment trying to help: Note `print` only print 15 digits after decimal. This is a known bug in swift (https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/348). You can get more decimals by convert it to a string specifically, below is an example of convert double to a string with 20 digits after the comma: `String(format: "%.20f", doubleValue)`

Comment: You can print about 50 digits with the calculation in the question.  `extension Double { func toString(withDigits digits: UInt) -> String { return String(format: "%.\(digits)f", self) } }`, `print(pi.toString(withDigits:50))`

Comment: I think there will never be endless numeric format in any programming language, because it would require endless memory. As Sulthan stated, you'll have to code tour number in your own format.